# How to run a linear regression using lm() on a subset in R after multiple imputation using MICE

Tags: r, subset, r-mice

I want to run a linear regression analysis on my multiple imputed data. I imputed my dataset using mice.  The formula I used to run a linear regression on my whole imputed set is as follows:

```
 mod1 <-with(imp, lm(outc ~ age + sex))
 pool_mod1 <- pool(mod1)
 summary(pool_mod1)
```

This works fine. Now I want to create a subset of BMI, by saying: I want to apply this regression analysis to the group of people with a BMI below 30 and to the group of people with a BMI above or equal to 30. I tried to do the following:

```
 mod2 <-with(imp, lm(outc ~ age + sex), subset=(bmi<30))
 pool_mod2 <- pool(mod2)
 summary(pool_mod2)

 mod3 <-with(imp, lm(outc ~ age + sex), subset=(bmi>=30))
 pool_mod3 <- pool(mod3)
 summary(pool_mod3)
```

I do not get an error, but the problem is: all three analysis give me exactly the same results. I thought this could be just the real life situation, however, if I use variables other than bmi (like blood pressure < 150), the same thing happens to me.

So my question is: how can I do subset analysis in R when the data is imputed using mice?

(BMI is imputed as well, I do not know if that is a problem?)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When posting a question, please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2359523) to aid others in answering your question.

Comment: Thank you, I will do this next time!

Answer (score 2):

You should place `subset` within `lm()`, not outside of it.

```
with(imp, lm(outc ~ age + sex, subset=(bmi<30)))
```

A reproducible example.

```
with(mtcars, lm(mpg ~ disp + hp)) # Both produce the same
with(mtcars, lm(mpg ~ disp + hp), subset=(cyl < 6))    

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         disp           hp  
   30.73590     -0.03035     -0.02484  


with(mtcars, lm(mpg ~ disp + hp, subset=(cyl < 6))) # Calculates on the subset

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         disp           hp  
   43.04006     -0.11954     -0.04609
```

Comment: You're welcome. Upvote and mark it as correct if it was useful and solved your issue.